# Paypal checkout for marketplace where buyer pays seller directly

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am running a marketplace for video games. When a buyer buys an item they can directly pay the seller through Paypal by setting the 'business' variable to the Paypal account of the seller in the link that will send the buyer over to Paypal to complete the purchase.

While this works *most* of the times, there are downsides to this approach as the website fully depends on receiving the IPN of the transaction. In very rare cases, Paypal fails to send the IPN (server logs show that there was no such request to the listener script – even hours later).

Is there a way to integrate a direct payment from buyer to seller where the website immediately gets feedback that the purchase has been completed (via JS-API or similar), so the website does not only depend on the IPNs?

I have seen a few similar questions on StackOverflow, but the solutions mentioned in answers have been deprecated as far as I can see (Adaptive Payments are no longer supported for new projects).

Answer (score 1):

Integrate PayPal checkout with a server-side pattern. Here is the front-end UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , which will call two routes on your server.

Those routes will in turn call the PayPal API to 'Set Up Transaction and 'Capture Transaction', respectively: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

---

The above has no dependency on asynchronous IPN or webhooks.

Since the buyer will be paying the seller and not your account, you can use the custom 'payee' object to specify this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: Thanks for this! Will I also receive notifications about following events like refunds which I need to track as well?

Comment: If you trigger the refunds from your own system via an API call, you'll have an immediate response to that API call. But if the refund is triggered by something else, e.g. in the PayPal account, you need a webhook to be notified of that event in an automated way.

Comment: One more thing: The currency for the transaction is determined by the way the JS-SDK is included. That's a bit of a show stopper as my cart could feature orders from different sellers and each order gets its own pay button. But if I can not set the currency for each Pay button, this will lead to trouble …

Comment: For best performance you should do an instant render: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/troubleshoot/performance/#instant-render , and yes the currency needs to be pre-determined as part of the query string since it determines what buttons could be shown.  But if you absolutely must have the currency determined after page load, I do know a solution for this if you want to ask the question

Comment: Thanks for that. At the moment I am struggling to even get the answer for the createOrder call right. I can't figure out what the JS-fetch call actually expect to get back from the server. I posted a new question … pretty frustrated.